# Why is my stdin redirection not being respected by an execl program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdin, io-redirection

I have been trying to create a wrapper for a Node.js commandline program in C++. At the moment, I have two threads. One is the main thread, where I will end up doing logic handling, and the other is mainly to run `execl()` on the commandline program I'm wrapping. The idea for what I'm expecting to happen is something like [this diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x187v.jpg) However, for whatever reason, my current implementation takes standard input and pipes it to both the main thread **and** the `execl` thread. Is there something I'm missing here?

Additionally, I would like to send input from the main thread to the `execl` thread as well, but I would assume that would come naturally from any solution to the above problem.

Here is the code I currently have. Thus far, I've researched into `pipe` and `fork`, as well as redirecting the standard streams with `std::stream.rdbuf()`. None seem to have worked the way I want them to, but I've had the most luck with the `std::stream` method thus far. Preferably, the solution would contain more modern C++, but standard C would work fine as well.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <signal.h>

#define OUTPUT_PSHOW output_to_stream(touser, touser_buf)

int fd_link[2];
bool should_thread_continue = true;

void output_to_stream(std::ostream& stream, std::stringstream& sstream)
{
    while (sstream.str().size() == 0) continue;
    std::string out;
    while (std::getline(sstream, out))
    {
        stream << out;
    }
    stream << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(void)> run_showdown = [](){
        close(fd_link[0]);
        dup2(fd_link[1], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd_link[1]);

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
            throw "Forking failed :(";
        
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // Child
            execl(/*program and args here */, NULL);
            should_thread_continue = false;
            exit(1);
        }
        
        while (should_thread_continue) continue;

        // send sigint to the pid
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
    };

    // Buffers
    std::stringstream toprgm_buf;
    std::stringstream touser_buf;
    std::stringstream in_buf;

    // New streams
    std::ostream touser(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::iostream toprgm(toprgm_buf.rdbuf());
    std::istream in(std::cin.rdbuf());
    
    // Stream Redefinitions
    std::cout.rdbuf(touser_buf.rdbuf());
    std::cin.rdbuf(toprgm.rdbuf());

    if (pipe(fd_link) == -1)
    {
        throw "Piping failed";
    }

    std::thread pshow(run_showdown);

    close(fd_link[1]);

    /********************
    * Here, in the real code, I would send some commands to the execl thread
    * from the main thread. It doesn't work, or help at the moment, so I'll skip it.
    *********************/

    bool should_exit = false;
    while (!should_exit)
    {
        std::string command = "";
        if (std::getline(in, command))
        {
            if (command == "exit")
            {
                should_exit = true;
                continue;
            }
            
            
            //toprgm << command;
            // OUTPUT_PSHOW;
        }
    }

    //kill thread
    should_thread_continue = false;
    while (!pshow.joinable()) continue;
    pshow.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `popen`?

Comment: @Elijay I remember that I did try `popen` when I first started trying to write this wrapper and it tended to work similarly to just setting up a pipe. I'll try that again and see if it happens to work better.

Comment: @Elijay I do remember why `popen` initially turned me off now - `popen` only opens a one way stream, which works for writing to the program, but not for getting output from the program. I reimplemented my current code with `popen` to give it a quick test, and the code now halts infinitely waiting for output from the command line program.

Answer (score 0):

(See also for instance
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos217/lectures/21IOProcessMgmt.pdf)

> Preferably, the solution would contain more modern C++, but standard C would work fine as well.

This is never a target. C++ is a tool, use it if it makes sense, otherwise use the correct interfaces,
you will need multiple interfaces here (c,posix,c++)
(But it would be good to tie the communication to the iostreams)

There might be tools that does this for you, popen/p2open (if you have it), boost possibly, but this is the basic principle anyways

Use case:

- Start applications, and set up communication to it.

Non-Goals:

- It is not a goal to redirect std::cin/std::cout et. al of the initial process
- It is not a goal to make a process server (fork early to avoid running out of memory)

Key decisions:

- For each started application have a communication queue of the  form
  (controller end) {in, out]  <-> [in, out]  (started application end)
- Use threads to read from/Write to the communication queue (optional)
- the lowest interface will be file descriptor based, feel free to map it to std::iostream / FILE * (fdopen)

Connection oriented shutdown is essentially:

- Close the  write end of the  initiating party
- The  other end which sits in read will have that read return 0
- This end  responds to read returning 0 by closing its  write  end (and also closes its read end)
- Which goes back to the initiating side where read will return 0 (where it closes its  read end)

So, like this:

- Initiator -- closewrite
- OtherEnd -- read -> 0
- OtherEnd -- closewrite
- OtherEnd -- closeread
- Initiator -- read -> 0
- Initiator -- closeread

(For sockets use shutdown, for pipes use close, in addition for started applications
there is also wait/kill)

and you will have to handle SIGPIPE,EPIPE which is the case if you do not do the shutdown
properly. That is, you close your read end, and the other party tries to write
(i.e. application crash, kill, etc)

Something like this

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

// Drop this
// #define OUTPUT_PSHOW output_to_stream(touser, touser_buf)


// Instances of this type serves two purposes, on the initiator end
// it is the front end to the started application, on the client  end
// it is the front end to the controller (Not much going on for this part)
class Program
{
public:
    ~Program();
    Program(const std::string &application);
    void send(const char *str) const;
    void shutdown();
    // Future:: tie m_fd_read to some output receiver
    // Future:: shutdown logic, from both ends, destructor, wait, kill functions
    // Future:: octet orientet interface, or character based
    // Future:: std::ostream & os();
    // Future:: std::istream & is();
private:
    pid_t m_pid = -1;
    std::string m_application; // Not used yet
    std::thread m_readThread;
    FILE *m_fp_read = NULL;
    FILE *m_fp_write = NULL;
    std::stringstream toprgm_buf; // Not used yet
    std::stringstream touser_buf; // Not used yet
};

Program::~Program()
{
    shutdown();
}

void Program::send(const char *str) const
{
    fprintf(m_fp_write, "%s", str);
    fflush(m_fp_write);
}

void Program::shutdown()
{
    if (m_pid != 0)
    {
        fclose(m_fp_write);    // Shutdown logic, close write  end
        m_readThread.join();  // Wait for read to  return 0
        int status = 0;
        waitpid(m_pid, &status, 0);
        fclose(m_fp_read);  // Shutdown done, close read end
    }
    m_pid = 0;
    m_fp_read = 0;
    m_fp_write = 0;
}

Program::Program(const std::string &application)
{
    //   set up your file  descriptors, std::iostreans,
    //   also call fork/exec
    int fd_stdin_link[2]  = { -1, -1 };
    int fd_stdout_link[2] = { -1, -1 };
    if (pipe(fd_stdin_link) == -1)
    {
        throw "Piping failed";
    }
    if (pipe(fd_stdout_link) == -1) // Also stderr probably
    {
        throw "Piping failed";
    }

    m_pid = fork();
    assert(m_pid != -1);
    if (m_pid != 0) // In parent
    {
        int fd_read  = fd_stdout_link[0]; // Read end of the  stdout pipe
        int fd_write = fd_stdin_link[1];  //Write end of the stdin pipe
        if (close(fd_stdout_link[1]) != 0)
        { 
            abort();
        }
        if (close(fd_stdin_link[0]) != 0)
        { 
            abort();
        }
        m_fp_read = fdopen(fd_read, "rt");
        m_fp_write = fdopen(fd_write, "wt");
        fd_read = -1; // fdopen takes ownership
        fd_write = -1; // fdopen takes ownership
        m_readThread = std::thread([&](){
            char buf[10240] = "";
            while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, m_fp_read))
            {
                fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), stdout);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        });
        //Exercise, connect the  fds to the iostreams
    }
    else // In Child
    {
        dup2(fd_stdin_link[0], fileno(stdin));   // redirect stdin in forked application
        dup2(fd_stdout_link[1], fileno(stdout)); // redirect stdin in forked application
        close(fd_stdin_link[1]);
        close(fd_stdout_link[0]);
        // And these, since we  duo2'ed them
        close(fd_stdin_link[0]);
        close(fd_stdout_link[1]);

        //This is where you exec
        char buf[10240] = "";
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) // Shutdown logic from other end, wait for read to return 0
        {
            printf("Processed [%s]\n", buf);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Program program("Hello");
    program.send("This is a line");
    program.shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```